Ubuntu wallpapers 24.04
I have installed wallpapers from ubuntu-wallpapers-noble package. Is there the GPL licence for them? May I publish screenshots in web?

Look at the right hand side of this link. The files are copyrighted so I would say no. https://packages.ubuntu.com/uk/source/noble/ubuntu-wallpapers

Ok, thanks. I will vote the answer.

Look at the right hand side of this link. The files are copyrighted so I would say no.
Ubuntu Packages

This answer is likely not correct. The wallpapers are licensed with CC-BY-SA-3.0 so they can be freely used provided credit is given.

CC licence is fine. I have placed one screenshot.
